# Seg fault trying to generate all possibilities from multiple types of an item

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, segmentation-fault, permutation

So I've got this method working such that it works when the data set is small.  However, when it gets just a little bit bigger....

The intent of this script is to find every possible set combination without duplicates.  So that I can store them in a database table.

```
set 1: [701,744,410,646,723,434]
set 2: [701,744,410,646,723,435]
set 3: etc..
```

I should also note that I need to keep the relationships with the original keys.  So items in type1 can not be moved to any other type.   Hope that makes sense.

```
Collecting pieces...
  pieces[type1] = [701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722]
  pieces[type2] = [744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765]
  pieces[type3] = [410, 412, 413, 414, 415, 419, 422, 424, 426, 427, 429, 372, 374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 385, 395, 397, 399, 401]
  pieces[type4] = [646, 647, 649, 651, 653, 655, 657, 671, 672, 673, 674, 679, 681, 684, 686, 688, 691, 695, 697, 698, 699, 700]
  pieces[type5] = [723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743]
  pieces[type6] = [434, 435, 438, 440, 443, 446, 447, 462, 464, 467, 469, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 494, 496]
Took 0.4265 seconds to collect.

Generating possibilities...
/Projects/my_project/lib/tasks/possibilities.rake:109: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Yep, segfault.

Here's the code I'm using to make it happen.

```
def permutations!(input)
  permutations_start = Time.now
  puts "Generating possibilities..."
  input.each do |key, possibilities|
    possibilities.map!{|p| {key => p} }
  end

  digits = input.keys.map!{|key| input[key] }

  # This is the line that seems to want to cry.
  result = digits.shift.product(*digits)

  puts "# of generated possibilities: #{result.length}"
  puts "Took #{(Time.now - permutations_start).round(4)} seconds to generate.\n\n"

  return result
end

pieces = {}
pieces['type1'] = [701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722]
pieces['type2'] = [744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765]
pieces['type3'] = [410, 412, 413, 414, 415, 419, 422, 424, 426, 427, 429, 372, 374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 385, 395, 397, 399, 401]
pieces['type4'] = [646, 647, 649, 651, 653, 655, 657, 671, 672, 673, 674, 679, 681, 684, 686, 688, 691, 695, 697, 698, 699, 700]
pieces['type5'] = [723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743]
pieces['type6'] = [434, 435, 438, 440, 443, 446, 447, 462, 464, 467, 469, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 494, 496]
possibilities = permutations!(pieces)
```

Comment: What is your intention with this script? What is the ideal outcome?

Comment: I should also note, that if you execute this code with fewer pieces it works.  Just at this scale it seems to blow up.

Comment: that's going to chew through a lot of memory - on my machine memory usage hit 10 gigs before I got a result back

Comment: Yeah exactly.  I'm not sure how to handle this at this point.

Comment: Personally i wouldn't calculate all the possibilities up front - it easy enough to generate them incrementally I think, and you can still have it work as an enumerator

Comment: Unfortunately, the combinations must be done up front.  The outcome of  the different combinations generate metrics that will need to be sortable and filterable.  So if I try and do it on the fly, I'd be doing this every time.  Which is not ideal.

Comment: If they're being stored in a database, then do them iteratively and write each row once you've computed it. You can easily/quickly do a search against the DB to find previously computed rows. Trading off speed for memory is a common issue, and is why we use databases -- you can access terabytes of data at a reasonable speed from a modest sized machine. If you absolutely have to have it all in RAM then be prepared to spend some money for chips.

Comment: Yeah, I was just talking with my brother about potentially having to do that.  I'm worried about the temp space on the database tables causing a lot of thrashing.

Comment: I should also note... the types are variable as well.  So it could be 6 types or it could be 18 types.

Answer (score 0):

So far as memory it looks okay.  CPU is pegged just like before although I expected that.

The bulk of the time now is storing the records in the database.  I wish I could use activerecord-import or a bulk insert to get it done faster, but I have to do calculations on the groups before I save them.  So I set it up as a before_save hook so it would be taken care of in the model.

At the current rate it will take about months to get all the data in the database.

```
def generate(input)
  input.each do |key, possibilities|
    possibilities.map!{|p| {key => p} }
  end

  digits = input.keys.map!{ |key| input[key] }

  i = 1
  shifted = digits.shift
  shifted.each do |item|
    puts "Generating groups #{i} of #{shifted.length}..."
    permutations_start = Time.now
    results = [item].product(*digits)
    puts "# of generated groups in the set number - #{i}: #{results.length}"
    puts "Took #{(Time.now - permutations_start).round(4)} seconds to generate.\n\n"

    # Storing the groups
    puts "Storing groups..."
    storing_start = Time.now
    results.each { |item| Group.create!(item.reduce({}, :update)) }
    puts "Took #{(Time.now - storing_start).round(4)} seconds to store.\n\n"

    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

Example output:

```
Collecting pieces...
  possibilities['type1'] = [701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722]
  possibilities['type2'] = [744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765]
  possibilities['type3'] = [410, 412, 413, 414, 415, 419, 422, 424, 426, 427, 429, 372, 374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 385, 395, 397, 399, 401]
  possibilities['type4'] = [646, 647, 649, 651, 653, 655, 657, 671, 672, 673, 674, 679, 681, 684, 686, 688, 691, 695, 697, 698, 699, 700]
  possibilities['type5'] = [723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743]
  possibilities['type6'] = [434, 435, 438, 440, 443, 446, 447, 462, 464, 467, 469, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 494, 496]
Took 0.4248 seconds to collect.

Generating groups 1 of 22...
There were 4,919,376 groups in the set number 1.
Took 1.819 seconds to generate.

Storing Groups...
250 items took 11.7158 seconds
250 items took 11.5094 seconds
250 items took 11.6994 seconds
250 items took 11.5678 seconds
250 items took 11.5529 seconds
```

Comment: Turned off validation that helps a bit but still ~days to get all the data in.